# how to populate a two drop down lists in a dynamically generated row

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

EDIT: my problem is I can't Populate drop down lists in the dynamically generated new row .

```
$('#Title_ID option').clone().appendTo('#NewTitle_ID');
$('#Stuff_ID option').clone().appendTo('#NewStuff_ID');
```

those are the lines that do the cloning of the ddl

---

I'm trying to generate a new row with two drop down lists in it when the user clicks on a "Add New Row" button. the problem is when clicking, it generates the row and it clones the options on the ddl of the first dynamically generated row and every new row , their ddls are empty and it gets generated inside the first ddl
[image]

the view :

```
<div class="form-group">
<label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="Account">
Account <span class="required">*</span>
</label>
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">

                                                                @Html.DropDownList("Account_ID", null, "", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", Name = "AccID", ID = "Account_ID", required = "required" })
</div>
                                                        </div>
                                                        @if (Model != null)
                                                        {
                                                            for (int i = 0; i < Model.mannings.Count; i++)
                                                            {
                                                                //ManningPlanItem


                                                                <div class="x_content">
                                                                    <!-- start accordion -->
                                                                    <div class="accordion" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
                                                                        <div class="panel">

                                                                            <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
                                                                                <td class="panel-body">
                                                                                    <table id="TableToBeEdited" class="table table-bordered">
                                                                                        <thead>
                                                                                            <tr>
                                                                                                <th></th>
                                                                                                <th>Title</th>
                                                                                                <th>Type</th>
                                                                                                <th>Jan</th>
                                                                                                <th>Feb</th>
                                                                                                <th>March</th>
                                                                                                <th>Apr</th>
                                                                                                <th>May</th>
                                                                                                <th>June</th>
                                                                                                <th>July</th>
                                                                                                <th>Aug</th>
                                                                                                <th>Sep</th>
                                                                                                <th>Oct</th>
                                                                                                <th>Nov</th>
                                                                                                <th>Dec</th>
                                                                                            </tr>
                                                                                        </thead>
                                                                                        <tbody>
                                                                                            <tr id="tablerow0">
                                                                                                <th scope="row">0</th>
                                                                                                <td>

                                                                                                    @Html.DropDownList("Title_ID", null, "", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", Name = "mannings[0].Title_ID", ID = "Title_ID" })

                                                                                                </td>
                                                                                                <td>

                                                                                                    @Html.DropDownList("Stuff_ID", null, "", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", Name = "mannings[0].Stuff_ID", ID = "Stuff_ID" })
                                                                                                </td>
                                                                                                <td>
                                                                                                    <input type="number" name="mannings[0].Jan" class="form-control" />
                                                                                                </td>
                                                                                                <td>
                                                                                                    <input type="number" name="mannings[0].Feb" class="form-control" />
                                                                                                </td>
                                                                                                <td>
                                                                                                    <input type="number" name="mannings[0].Mar" class="form-control" />
                                                                                                </td>
                                                                                                <td>
                                                                                                    <input type="number" name="mannings[0].Apr" class="form-control" />
                                                                                                </td>
                                                                                                <td>
                                                                                                    <input type="number" name="mannings[0].May" class="form-control" />
                                                                                                </td>
                                                                                                <td>
                                                                                                    <input type="number" name="mannings[0].Jun" class="form-control" />
                                                                                                </td>
                                                                                                <td>
                                                                                                    <input type="number" name="mannings[0].Jul" class="form-control" />
                                                                                                </td>
                                                                                                <td>
                                                                                                    <input type="number" name="mannings[0].Aug" class="form-control" />
                                                                                                </td>
                                                                                                <td>
                                                                                                    <input type="number" name="mannings[0].Sep" class="form-control" />
                                                                                                </td>
                                                                                                <td>
                                                                                                    <input type="number" name="mannings[0].Oct" class="form-control" />
                                                                                                </td>
                                                                                                <td>
                                                                                                    <input type="number" name="mannings[0].Nov" class="form-control" />
                                                                                                </td>
                                                                                                <td>
                                                                                                    <input type="number" name="mannings[0].Dec" class="form-control" />
                                                                                                </td>
                                                                                                <td>
                                                                                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="RemoveRow(0);">Delete</button>

                                                                                                </td>

                                                                                            </tr>
                                                                                        </tbody>
                                                                                    </table>
                                                                            </div>
                                                                        </div>

                                                                    </div>
                                                                </div>

                                                            }
                                                        }
<div class="form-group">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="AdditionButton">
                                            Add New Row
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="col-md-5 col-md-10 ">
                                            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary js-create" />

                                        </div>
                                    </div>
```

the jquery i'm using:

```
<script>

    var counter = 1;
    $(function () {
        $('#AdditionButton').click(function () {

            $(

                ' <tr id="tablerow' + counter + '"> <th scope="row">' + counter + '</th><td><select id="NewTitle_ID" name ="mannings[' + counter + '].Title_ID" class="form-control"></select></td>'
                + '<td><select id="NewStuff_ID" name = "mannings[' + counter + '].Stuff_ID" class="form-control"></select></td>'
                + '<td><input type="number" name="mannings[' + counter + '].Jan" class="form-control" /></td>'
                + '<td><input type="number" name="mannings[' + counter + '].Feb" class="form-control" /></td>'
                + '<td><input type="number" name="mannings[' + counter + '].Mar" class="form-control" /></td>'
                + '<td><input type="number" name="mannings[' + counter + '].Apr" class="form-control" /></td>'
                + '<td><input type="number" name="mannings[' + counter + '].May" class="form-control" /></td>'
                + '<td><input type="number" name="mannings[' + counter + '].Jun" class="form-control" /></td>'
                + '<td><input type="number" name="mannings[' + counter + '].Jul" class="form-control" /></td>'
                + '<td><input type="number" name="mannings[' + counter + '].Aug" class="form-control" /></td>'
                + '<td><input type="number" name="mannings[' + counter + '].Sep" class="form-control" /></td>'
                + '<td><input type="number" name="mannings[' + counter + '].Oct" class="form-control" /></td>'
                + '<td><input type="number" name="mannings[' + counter + '].Nov" class="form-control" /></td>'
                + '<td><input type="number" name="mannings[' + counter + '].Dec" class="form-control" /></td>'
                +'</tr > ').appendTo('#TableToBeEdited');

            counter++;

            $('#Title_ID option').clone().appendTo('#NewTitle_ID');
            $('#Stuff_ID option').clone().appendTo('#NewStuff_ID');
           
            return false;

        });


    });

</script>
```

I searched various solutions but they either not working or giving a different response like the drop down list issue.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you make a working demo of your code in https://jsfiddle.net/? We can see whats the issue. Thanks

Comment: @maverickosama92  it's a .net view syntax . I'm going to edit the post so i can make the problem more clear .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using [`id selector`](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/sel_id.asp) `#NewTitle_ID` which will select first element with `id` `NewTitle_ID`. As you are having `same` `id` for all dynamically created rows it will always clone your options to first one only.

To solve your problem you can use [`attribute selector` `[]`](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/sel_attribute_equal_value.asp) like `$("[name = 'xyz']")` will select all elements with `name` attribute equals to `xyz`.

In your can you can use it as `'[name="mannings[' + counter + '].Stuff_ID"]'`. Your append code will be like below.

```
$('#Title_ID option').clone().appendTo('[name="mannings[' + counter + '].Title_ID"]');
$('#Stuff_ID option').clone().appendTo('[name="mannings[' + counter + '].Stuff_ID"]');
```

Comment: It worked . I added it before  ```counter ++``` and it worked. Thank you